Is there any electronic devices that maintain charged state?
I want to know how to make electronic devices that are continuously charged to + or - state on which surface when voltage is applied to utilize the dielectric polarization property, or if there are any ready-made products already on sale. The stronger the charge, the better.

Like an electret ?

@PM 2Ring   Oh maybe that's good. However, just in case, I would like to know if there are any single poles on the entire surface.

The Van de Graaff generator?

@ThePhoton It's amazing invention. It's a little expensive, but it's worth considering. Thanks!
